# Property does not exist on this collection instance while trying to iterate through foreach

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to display an edit form with current value from the database.

Here's the Controlller.

```
 public function edit(PenerimaanHadiahSponsor $id)
    {
        $collection = PenerimaanHadiahSponsor::find($id);
        $dataanak = Anak::find($id);
        $datatp = TipeHadiahSponsor::find($id);

       // dd($dataanak);
        return view('sponsor.penerimaan.updatetrx', compact('collection', 'dataanak', 'datatp'));
    }
```

For now, I try to iterate the $datanak collection, but it returns that property [id] does not exist on the collection.

Here's the blade view file

```
<div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="basic-form-gender">Pilih Anak</label>
                    <select class="form-select" id="basic-form-gender" aria-label="Default select example" name="id_anak">
                      <option selected="selected">Pilih Anak yg Dapat Hadiah</option>
                      @foreach ($dataanak as $dtanak)
                        <option value="{{ $dtanak -> id }}">{{ $dtanak -> fullname }}</option>
                      @endforeach
                    </select>
                  </div>
```

I expect that it could return this data because it has relation with my curent model table which named penerimaan_data_sponsors
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/856336794068189208/1051057589376532580/image.png

When I try to dd($dataanak) with this method:

```
$dataanak = Anak::where('id', 1)->get();
```

It returns the collection using id = 1, but when I used the current data id which is 12, it's returns blank array. Because the current data I want to edit had id 12.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/856336794068189208/1051058294464188456/image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fix was this. I removed the model 'PenerimaanHadiahSponsor' from edit function.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $collection = PenerimaanHadiahSponsor::find($id);
    $dataanak = Anak::find($id);
    $datatp = TipeHadiahSponsor::find($id);

    dd($dataanak->fullname);
    // return view('sponsor.penerimaan.updatetrx', compact('collection', 'dataanak', 'datatp'));
}
```